# where can I find ELK version in REST API?

Tags: python, rest, elastic-stack

I would like to get ELK version through REST API or parse html.

I search in API documentation without finding anything

Re-edit:
In python ... i'm not found better than

```
re.findall(r"version&quot;:&quot;(\d\.\d\.\d)&quot", requests.get(my_elk).content.decode())[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch gives JSON, not HTML. So, you could use `jq`

```
$ curl -s localhost:9200 | jq '.version.number'
6.6.0
```

In Python, please don't use `re` module... Use `json` module and actually parse that content

Answer (score 0):

There's no HTML, but if you call `GET /` in Kibana's Console or `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/`, the return will be:

```
{
  "name" : "instance-0000000039",
  "cluster_name" : "c2edd39f6fa24b0d8e5c34e8d1d19849",
  "cluster_uuid" : "VBkvp8OmTCaVuVvMioS3SA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "a9861f4",
    "build_date" : "2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So all you need to do is get `version.number` from the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using the `requests` library, why not use the `json` method to parse the result?

```
requests.get(my_elk).json()["version"]["number"]
```